# Access Shared Folder on GCP Windows VM Instance

Tags: windows, file, google-cloud-platform

I've set up Windows Server VM instance on GCP. I've set up a static IP for that server and I'm able to remote desktop in without problem using the inside IP address as I have a VPN connection between my on premesis network and my GCP network. On the Windows Server, I've set up a sharing folder with the proper permissions.

Now, on my local PC running Windows 10, I'm trying to map a network a drive to that shared folder on the VM. What's the correct path to specific it to map to? I tried \\ but it doesn't work.

I have enabled network discovery, checked all firewall rules and enabled file and print sharing.

I can ping from my local pc to my Windows VM instance.

Thanks in advance

I have opened up the following ports on GCP Network:

tcp-access Ingress Apply to all IP ranges: 192.168.84.0/24

tcp:135-139
udp:445

Still unable to access. 
I thought by default google had all ingress ports open on the local IP?

I checked the firewall on the server and everything is open as well.

Thanks in advnace.

Comment: You will need to open ports in both the Windows Firewall and the GCP firewall. Which ports do you have open. Edit your question with details. TCP and UDP ports 135 - 139 and 445. Once you have there required ports open test with `net use \\server_ip_address\share_name N:` change command to fit your setup.

Comment: Do you still have an issue? Have you opened ports at both sides as it was suggested by *@John Hanley*? If yes, please check open ports with [nmap](https://nmap.org/download.html) from both sides and share results in your question.